# Excel 2013 displaying 'zoomed' UI on Windows 8.1 with high DPI screen?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-excel

I'm using a high DPI laptop - 13" 1080p screen - which Windows 8.1 usually manages very nicely for modern sofware. Old stuff looks blurry, PowerShell is bizarrely unusable, everything else pretty much fine.

For some reason, Excel 2013 changed earlier. It's now displaying like an old pre-DPI change program - large, and blurry. I've had a look but I can't find a setting to change this. What have I done wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: What is scaling set to?

Comment: Default, 150% (if I tick the 'one for all displays' box) or middle of the slider.

Comment: And I suppose 100% fixes these issues?

Comment: Can't be certain because that only kicks in on a new login and it seems a reboot has cleared the problem, but that's system wide which my problem wasn't - so I don't think so. But it's working now, weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was just 'one of those things' - it's cleared up after a reboot.